# What method for detecting image type is more reliable: content-type or MIME-sniffing?

Tags: windows, image, winapi, file-format

I want to detect the image file format in a Windows application. Images are either downloaded from the web (via HTTP) or loaded from local files.

Which method is more reliable for detecting the image file format for the files, downloaded from the Web?

- File extension is the most obvious way, but it is often not correct or is missing
- HTTP header content-type is a good candidate (I can check image type without downloading it via HTTP HEAD command), but sometimes it is not set properly
- MIME-sniffing (via Windows API FindMimeFromData command or by manually checking file content for known signatures) is the last method I am aware of, but I've never used it and I am not sure if it is reliable

So, what should I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the data itself is more reliable, but you need to add checks for each specific type you want to detect and handle. Note that if you're using the content type, something down the line has to determine this information.
Misconfigured servers and data guessing frequently get the wrong content type for Windows gadget, Java jar, etc that are all based on the zip format, for which you'd need another way to differentiate the types (falling back to extension, etc).

Comment: Finally, I have decided to use FindMimeFromData - it checks for the all common image file formats, which is fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

Most image file formats contain an identifier at a specific byte offset. For example, a JPG image will have the string `JFIF` at offset 6, PNG files have `PNG` at offset 1, GIF files have either `GIF89` or `GIF87` at offset 0, BMP files have `BM` at offset 0, and so forth.